# Best practice for ensuring test methods order

Tags: django-testing

Django 1.9. I want to test that input forms are invisible normally. And only when a user presses toggle menu button, login and password input elements appear.

The problem is that this is all about methods of a class. I want to be sure that one method executes before another. I have found this solution with 0 and 1 in method names.

```
class FuncTestTablets(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        pass

    def test_0_tablets_login_input_form_absent(self):
        # At home page with tablet screen size Edith sees no login input element.
        ## 0 is for stating explicitly that this test goes before the ones with 1 in their name. 
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
        login_input = self.browser.find_element_by_id('login')        
        self.assertFalse(login_input.is_displayed(), "Login input element is visible on large devices")

    def test_1_tablets_login_input_form_present_when_menu_button_pressed(self):
        # At home page Edith presses menu button and login input appears.
        ## 1 is for stating explicitly that this test goes after the ones with 0 in their name.
        menu_button = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('navbar-toggle')
        menu_button.click()
        login_input = self.browser.find_element_by_id('login')
        self.assertTrue(login_input.is_displayed(), "Login input element is not visible on tablet devices when menu button is pressed.")
```

This seems to work. Could you tell me is there some generally known methodology for such cases. Maybe some best practice.

I've just started Django and I don't think that my solution is at once the best.

That's why I decided to ask you. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is that the order of your test methods does not matter at all and if you inherit from [`django.test.TestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase), it should not matter. I have, however, been in the situation where I wanted to test a feature `'foo'` in one method and then, for convenience (like not having to wrap it in `try-except`), assume that it is working properly in other methods that test something else (`'bar'`).

I named my test methods

```
test_a_foo
test_b_bar
```

This seems more appropriate then using numbers because tests are executed in lexicographic order where, e.g.

```
test_11_eleven
```

is executed before

```
test_2_two
```

If you then have to insert another test later, you can still change the names to:

```
test_b1_first_b
test_b2_second_b
```